# Configuring Varnish-4 with Virtual-hosts on nginx

Tags: nginx, configuration, virtualhost, varnish, virtual-hosts

I’m getting stuck trying to implement Varnish 4.0 on Virtual Hosts set up using nginx.  I have tried to configure the backend per my reading but I can’t seem to get varnish to work on anything but the main IP address.  For this example, I will use site1*com and 12:34:56:78 for my IP address.

Also, I had to change the . to * due to reputation points and I'm not trying to link an address, just express what i have typed.

I have this in nginx.conf:

```
…
server {
listen  8080;
root         /usr/share/nginx/html;
location / {
}
…
```

and I have this typed in varnish.params:

```
…
#VARNISH_LISTEN_ADDRESS=“12:34:56:78” (I know this is commented out)
VARNISH_LISTEN_PORT=80

# Admin interface listen address and port
VARNISH_ADMIN_LISTEN_ADDRESS=12:34:56:78
VARNISH_ADMIN_LISTEN_PORT=6082
```

In default.vcl I have typed:

```
…
backend default {
.host = “127.0.0.1";
.port = "8080";
}
backend site1 {
.host = “127.0.0.1";
.port = "8080"; 
}

…
…
sub vcl_recv {
if (req.http.host ~ "www*site1*com$") 
set req.http.host = "127.0.0.1";
set req.backend_hint = smith;
}
else {
set req.http.host = "127.0.0.1";
set req.backend_hint = default;
}
```

Finally, for my site1*com*conf file (for the virtual host file) I have set up the following:

```
…
server {
listen     127.0.0.1:8080;
server_name site1.com www*site1*com;
…
```

From here, if I type curl -I http://12:34:56:78 I get the following:

```
  HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    Server: nginx
    Date: Fri, 15 Jan 2016 15:09:51 GMT
    Content-Type: text/html
    Content-Length: 3700
    Last-Modified: Sun, 04 Oct 2015 07:53:44 GMT
    ETag: "5610db08-e74"
    X-Varnish: 2
    Age: 0
    Via: 1.1 varnish-v4
    Connection: keep-alive
```

Awesome.  But then when I type curl -I http://www*site1*com I get the following:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.0.15
Date: Fri, 15 Jan 2016 22:57:30 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Connection: keep-alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=15
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Length: 4918
Expires: -1
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-Powered-By: ARR/2.5
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
```

No varnish.  As a test, I also tried curl -I http://site1*com and got the following:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Server: nginx
Date: Fri, 15 Jan 2016 15:10:16 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Connection: keep-alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=15
Content-Length: 154
```

To me, it seems like varnish is installed and works on the IP address, but something is getting lost in translation when I go to the virtual host.  I’m hoping its a simple error in my syntax or in how I’m testing, but I am stumped.

Any help would be so greatly appreciated.

Comment: I apologize in advance for having to change the . to *.  It makes it a little difficult to read.  I also could have done my markdown better.  I will try to edit it when I get time later today.  But I know I have made a confusing topic a little messier and, again, sorry.

Comment: As a second comment, I noticed that when I enabled ngx_pagespeed it also works on 12:34:56:78 but not on www*site1*com.  So maybe it is an error with how I set up my server block?

Comment: Does your www* resolve to an IPv4 or IPv6 ip? It seems that perhaps you're listening on an ipV6 address (assuming that's what the 12:34.. is), however it's not clear if you're listening on the ipV4 version of the site, which nginx may be doing.